# How can I keep a modal dialog after a submit?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a way so that when clicking the submit button or a link, do the submission
 and remain in the same modal dialog.
My program has two forms within the same dialog, one is not shown until the first is submited  and i would like that on submiting the first form load, within the same dialog.

For the load dialog i have this code:

```
function loadDialog(tag, event, target) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $loading = $('<img src="../../Content/assets/images/nivo-loader.gif" alt="loading" class="ui-loading-icon">');
        var $url = $(tag).attr('href');
        var $title = $(tag).attr('title');
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>');
        $dialog.empty();
        $dialog
        .append($loading)
        .load($url)
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false
            , title: $title
            , width: 600
            , modal: true
            , minHeight: 200
            , show: 'fade'
            , hide: 'fade'
        });
});
```

Then in the Create.cshtml:

```
@model Mvcproject.Models.MyModel
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("input[type=submit]")
        .button(
        );
    $('a.modalDlg2').live("click", function (event) { loadDialog('#modalDlg', event, '#Receipt Create'); });

    /*$('input.Submit').live("click", function (event) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadDialog('#modalDlg', event, '#Receipt Create');
    });*/

    $(".demo button").button({
        icons:
    {
        primary: 'ui-icon-plusthick'
    }
    });
});
</script>
<h2>
Add line</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset class="createReceipt">
    <legend>User login</legend>
    @if (ViewBag.Created)
    {
        <table class="createTable">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4">
                    <img src="../../Images/no_image.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
                </td>
                <th colspan="1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Name)
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email)
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Email)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Password)
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Password)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!--User picture-->
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" value="browse" name="Browse" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/jpg" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="Submit" value="Create" />
            <buttonreceipt style="width: 150px; text-align: left">@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create")</buttonreceipt>
        </p>
    }
    else
    { 
        <!-- This will be displayed when user data is submited and inserted into database-->
        <table class="createTable">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Name)
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="1">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Email)
                </th>
                <td colspan="5">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Email)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <img src="@Model.User.Picture"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</fieldset>        


}
@if (!ViewBag.Created)
{
    @Html.Partial("_AddUserInformation");
}
```

ViewBag.Created is either false or true depending on if user data has been inserted with success into database and that functionality is already done.
And _AddUserInformation.cshtml has other information for the user that is trying to register, like address and country...
Hope this explains better my problem.

Comment: need to improve your question so others who have nver seen your app can understand some basics...like "load from where"? Hard to manipulate and write code for invisible html

Comment: Should be no problem if you are using ajax. For me to help you though, you will need  to post the code, or at least some example code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a sample code for your question if possible to improve the post accuracy and get better results. Have a great day :)

Comment: Already done some editting, sorry but i could not explain better and probably it still isn't enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery post() function to send data to an address. You'll need to pick out the data from your fields manually using jQuery selectors (shouldn't be difficult) as well as configure a function to receive and treat the data. This link on post should give you what you need to get started. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks levib i did that and it helped me ;)